# How do I connect this for loop with my list?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make a program that does the following,

it "will allow the user to enter the rainfall statistics for 12 months into a list. The program should calculate the total rainfall for the year, the average rainfall for the year and the months with the highest and lowest rainfall."

Secondly, "Use a loop to ask the user for the rainfall amount for the month and store it in the list at the appropriate index for the month."

Lastly, ", you will need to set up a list of 12 elements containing the month names.   You can then use the loop counter as an index into the month names to get the correct month."

Here's what I have so far,

```
months = ['January','February', 
'March','April','May','June','July','August',
       'September','October','November','December']

for i in months:
float(input('What is the rainfall for ' + i + '?'))


print(months)

max_rain = max(months)
min_rain = min(months)
avg_rain = sum(months)/12
print(max_rain)
print(min_rain)
print(avg_rain)
```

I'm confused as to how to implement the index counter as the directions say and I am pretty lost as to what step to take next. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First I think you should use [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) for this purpose, it is more appropriated to this task.

Next, if using list as you are doing, in your loop, you just print a value, but you do not put the input value in any var.

```
months = ['January','February', 
'March','April','May','June','July','August',
       'September','October','November','December']

rain = []

for i in months:
    rainfall = (float(input('What is the rainfall for ' + i + '?')))
    while rainfall < 0 :
        print " Rainfall must be >= 0"
        rainfall = (float(input('What is the rainfall for ' + i + '?')))
    rain.append(rainfall)

print(rain)

max_rain = max(rain)
min_rain = min(rain)
avg_rain = sum(rain)/12
print(max_rain)
print(min_rain)
print(avg_rain)
```

This way you will print the results like this.

Output :

```
What is the rainfall for January?1
What is the rainfall for February?-2
 Rainfall must be >= 0
What is the rainfall for February?-2
 Rainfall must be >= 0
What is the rainfall for February?-2
 Rainfall must be >= 0
What is the rainfall for February?2
What is the rainfall for March?3
What is the rainfall for April?4
What is the rainfall for May?5
What is the rainfall for June?6
What is the rainfall for July?7
What is the rainfall for August?8
What is the rainfall for September?9
What is the rainfall for October?10
What is the rainfall for November?11
What is the rainfall for December?12
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0]
12.0
1.0
6.5
```

I still suggest you try to do the same with dictionaries, and then you will be able to get the max value of rain and it will be easy to find which month it was.

EDIT : Added the last requirement.

Comment: thank you for the quick response, this helped me understand it a lot better, the last requirement is that there's an "input validation –each rainfall amount should be a positive number." In order to do this would I simply do.  for i in months:
    rain.append(float(input('What is the rainfall for ' + i + '?')))
if rain < 0:
    print('Invalid Input')

Comment: You're right, a condition does the job here. 
I Edited my code with your last requirement. Please make sure you understand everything, and if it's not the case, feel free to ask which part you didn't understand. Additionally, don't forget that this is just one way to do it but there are many others.
And finally, don't forget to use the `code` format when you put some in your comments.

Comment: @Conn By the way, if the answer to your question has been given you can accept it (if it's good for you) ;)

Answer (score -1):

You could replace

```
for i in months:
```

with

```
for i, month in enumerate(months):
```

then you would have two variables in the loop body:
i with the loop counter and month with the name of the month.

Comment: `enumerate` works with 2 parameters: first is `iterable`, second is `start` which sets initial index (e. g. if you want indexing from 1, then you should specify `start = 1`)